# Getting wrong variable value on onResume after saving with SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, oncreate, onresume

I am trying to save **Boolean count** in `onPause` and retrieve that in `onResume` using `SharedPreference`. But when I launch the app first time I am getting `false` value of **count**. 
I don't know why. I searched my question could not find a matching answer.

Below is the code of one of my activity:

```
public class ListView extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private ArrayList<String> url= new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> listitems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter mAdapter;
    private android.widget.ListView listView;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private int posi;
    private boolean count =true;
    BroadcastReceiver onComplete;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        Log.d("count onCreate",String.valueOf(count));
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Count",0);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListView.this);
        final View coordinatorLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String uri=intent.getStringExtra("uri");

        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,listitems);
        listView = (android.widget.ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(uri);

        mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                String value= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                listitems.add(0,key);
                url.add(0,value);

                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                        if ((cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) ||
                                (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {

                            builder.setMessage("Do You Want To Download "+listitems.get(position)+" "+uri+ " ?");
                            builder.setTitle(R.string.confirm);
                            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.pdf);
                            builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    posi = position;
                                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(ListView.this, downloadService.class);
                                    intent1.putExtra("uri", url.get(position));
                                    startService(intent1);
                                    Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Downloading in Background, See Notification", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    View sbView = sb.getView();
                                    sbView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_orange));
                                    sb.show(); }
                            });
                            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                            alert1.show();
                        }
                        else {
                            final View coordinatorLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                            Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "No Internet Connection..!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            View sbView = sb.getView();
                            sbView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_orange));
                            sb.show();

                        }

                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something Went Wrong :(" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListView.this);
                builder.setTitle("Download Completed");
                builder.setMessage("Do You Want To Open "+listitems.get(posi)+" "+uri+ " ?");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.pdf);
                builder.setNegativeButton("Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Open", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Intent inten = new Intent(ListView.this,onDownload.class);
                        inten.putExtra("uri",url.get(posi));
                        startService(inten);

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
        };
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(onComplete);
        Log.d("count onPause",String.valueOf(count));
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("count",count).apply();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        count =sharedPreferences.getBoolean("count",true);
        Log.d("count onResume",String.valueOf(count));
        if (count){
            count=false;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Loading...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Logcats

> 07-24 19:15:25.478 19784-19784/com.example.mmstq.myapp
>   D/count onCreate: true
>
> 07-24 19:15:25.489 19784-19784/com.example.mmstq.myapp
>   D/count onResume: false

Comment: Sorry for my bad formatting. I am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your onCreate call isn't outputting the value of the shared preference, but the value of the count variable which is defaulted to true. We have no idea what the actual value is at that time, but given your onResume output its probably false.

Comment: I want to run the code inside if block in onResume method but as onPause did not run the  value of count should be true which is default value in case no value is stored. I did not touch the onStart method

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because when you run your app for the first time, `onResume()` runs, refer to the Activity life cycle of Android, see it here [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)
So you can handle it for the first time app loading.